# Wait for eglSwapBuffers posting to complete

Tags: framebuffer, egl, posting

I need to know when posting completes after eglSwapBuffers. I was thinking eglWaitNative might halt execution until positing is complete, but I find it unclear reading the spec, chapter 3.8:
https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/specs/eglspec.1.5.pdf

It would appear eglWaitNative is used to synchronizing "native" rendering API such as Xlib and GDI. However as far as I know eglSwapBuffers might be running on top of Wayland which can´t render shit. Still, it would seem reasonable to believe the EGL_CORE_NATIVE_ENGINE engine always points out the "marking engine" doing buffer swaps...

From 3.10.3 I read:

> Subsequent client API commands can be issued immediately, but will not
>   be executed until posting is completed.

I suppose I could do something like this but I´d rather use "pure" egl if possible:

```
eglSwapBuffers(...);
glClear(...); // "Dummy" command.
```

My project is using OpenGL Safety Critical profile 1.0.1, EGL 1.3 and some vendor specific extensions. Sync objects are not available.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "posting completes"? Are you trying to catch where the frame appears on the physical display? You may want to specify what system/platform you are using. I have a feeling that this might be very system dependent, if there's a reasonable way to do it at all.